# odoo 9 - Field does not exist

Tags: python, xml, orm, odoo, odoo-9

follow the documentation Odoo 9.0, I created a new module which I created a new model as follows:

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api

class payModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'payModel.payModel'
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'

    num_CN = fields.Char("CN°")
```

and my form view:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="payModel_form_view">
    <field name="name">payModel.num_CN</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='bank_account_id']" position="after">
                <field name="num_CN"/>
            </xpath>
        </data>
    </field>
</record>
```

I verirfy in Settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Models that the model and the field were added by success But I get this error :

> the num_CN does not exist

I try to add this field in employee form view by developer mode but I get the same error!

Can sameone help me what's missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - about your model.

`_name = 'payModel.payModel'` means that when you install module Odoo will create new table with name **payModel_payModel**. After this in the system will be your custom object - *payModel.payModel*.

`_inherit = 'hr.employee'` means that you expand table **hr_employee**(Odoo object - *hr.employee*).

If you want to create new table and use your new object you need to remove `_inherit = 'hr.employee'`. If you need to extend the *hr.employee*(for example add new fields or add some logic to model etc.) you need to remove  `_name = 'payModel.payModel'`

Second problem which can be it is *dependencies*. If your module depends from **hr** module you need to mark this in **__openerp__.py** of your module:

```
'depends': ['hr'],
```

And one more thing. Make sure that *models.py* is imported in **__init__.py** of your module. Restart openerp-server before updating your module after changes in **.py** files. Odoo does not see changes in **.py** files without restart.

Hope this helps you.