# Updating Fields in Existing Modules in Odoo 9

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-9

I am a newbie in odoo development. I already installed a module which is inheriting from Project module , which will add certain additional fields in Project section. But when I tried to add more field in module file & tried to upgrade,the new field is not uploading. I restarted the server & tried updating.. but its not working..can you please help me? My model wil be like this :-

```
class legacy_projects007(osv.osv):
  _inherit = "project.project"

  _columns = {
    'legacy_projects_amount': fields.float('Amount'),
    'legacy_projects_regdate': fields.date(),
    'legacy_projects_description': fields.text('Description'),
    'legacy_projects_enddate': fields.date(),
  }

  _defaults ={
    'legacy_projects_amount': "1000.0",
    'legacy_projects_description': "Description of Project Here",
  }
```

Comment: Check your dependencies and init.py. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490479/odoo-9-field-does-not-exist/35525253#35525253) may be useful. If the problem persists show structure of your module.

Answer (score 0):

1)first of all add module depends('project') in openerp.py file

2)when you are make new file this file will be add in init.py file.